# How is the ephemeral-storage of a container calculated by Kubernetes and can I query it with Prometheus?

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I'm trying to figure out how much ephemeral-storage my containers (or pods) or using.

[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68176966/956620) suggests that the `calcEphemeralStorage` function ([code here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/d88fadbd65c5e8bde22630d251766a634c7613b0/pkg/kubelet/stats/helper.go#L349)) is used to calculate the ephemeral-storage and to determine if the pod needs to be evicted.

I wonder if I can somehow read out this value and use it in prometheus to visualise the container's ephemeral-storage because now I'm flying blind. At some point, Kubernetes decides to evict a pod because it surpassed its ephemeral-storage limit but I have no idea what's taking up the storage.

I've found that the Prometheus variable `container_fs_usage_bytes` gives some information about this usage but this only works on Kubernetes 1.18 or lower.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up your cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: It's on bare metal (VM actually) set up with kubeadm. Kubernetes version 1.18